# how to fetch this query using 2 table

Tags: php, mysql

Hy I have 2  table
1.application
`id | name    | status`
`====================`
`1 | morvick  | complete`
`2 | siti     | prosess`
`3 | boby     | complete`
`

2.application_test
`id | application_id  | test_id | result`
`======================================`
`1 | 1  |              1 |       70`
`2 | 1  |              2 |       80`
`3 | 1  |              3 |       90`
`4 | 2  |              1 |       60`
`5 | 2  |              2 |       80`
`6 | 2  |              3 |       70`
`7 | 3  |              1 |       90`
`8 | 3  |              2 |       70`
`9 | 3  |              3 |       60`
`10| 3  |              4 |       80`
my Question is :
==================
1. how to find the maximum value at each test_id
2. how I can to get or total applicant_id where status complete
 
for example to be like this :
`test_id | result_max | total_applicant_status(complete)`
`1       | 90         | 2`
`2       | 80         | 2`
`3       | 90         | 2`
`4       | 80         | 1`

Comment: So what did you tired so far?

Comment: Hy  Basheer Ahmed, i'm tired how I can get or count applicant_id where status complete

Comment: @b4dQuetions check my updated answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: hy Redbeard011010 what the meaning status='complete', **1, 0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(value) FROM table WHERE test_id = 1;
```

or perhaps `SELECT value, test_id FROM table ORDER BY value DESC;`

and for the next part, this may give what you want.

```
SELECT at.test_id, MAX(at.result), COUNT(IF(status='complete', 1, 0)) FROM application a LEFT JOIN application_test at ON a.id = at.application_id GROUP BY application_id;
```

Comment: hy Redbeard011010 what the meaning status='complete', **1, 0** and it's not work

Comment: That is an IF coupled with a COUNT. Basically, if status = complete, it counts 1, otherwise, it counts 0. Can you tell me what you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: if I'm use your query, display test_id just one every applicant_id

Comment: Ah, try grouping by test_id instead, then, maybe.